# scale Maximum local port range

Tags: networking, mysql

I work as system administrator for a company and I found there is a server that run Ubuntu server 14.04, and MySQL server listener port is 83306.

How can I set up `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` higher than 65535?
I attach to this post a screenshot of client connection `mysqlworkbench`.
And I also did a telnet on this port in Windows.

[image: workbeanch conection accept]

[image: mysql workbench screenshot]

[image]

Comment: questions: 1. I can setup workbench to show a connection to port 1000000 but that does not mean it will open and not error out ;-) 2. Is that connection over TCP/IP? Cuz that is limited to 65534 and above it should not work... maybe the creator of that connection hacked something together? 3. using "root" for workbench connections is a BAD idea. An admin should know that and not use it.

Comment: "mysql server listener port is 83306". The answer should be, no it's not... like Rinzwind described.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output for `sudo netstat -tlnpu`. Then we can see what port mysql is really listening on, maybe it wraps and is actually 17770.

Answer (score 6):

Port numbers above 65535 not only violate the TCP standard, they're literally impossible because the TCP package header field for the port number can only hold numbers between 0 and 65535 (i. e. a 16-bit unsigned integer).

Answer (score 3):

The TCP protocol only *permits* ports between 1 and 65534, by its specification.  To try and force otherwise is to be noncompliant with the TCP protocol; it also is impossible to do because of the reasons David mentioned in their answer, it can only hold numbers between 0 and 65534, due to being a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Just get a random number generator, and generate a random port above 50000 but below 65534, and use that number.  Don't go breaking the TCP protocol just because you want to.